# Apparant inconsistency in DNA topology theory in formation of origin of replication

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I'm studying an introductory course in genetics and came across something I don't fully understand. I obviously used Google to find where I'm thinking wrong, but I still can't understand it.

To catalyse strand separation, a negative supercoil is introduced due to the binding of DnaA-proteins, so the strands aren't being broken to form the supercoil. This means that the linking number must stay the same. Due to the negative supercoil the Writhe is decreased by 1, and thus the Twist must increase by 1 (because Lk stays the same).

A higher twist means that the DNA strand is overwound. Meanwhile my Textbook says this negative supercoiling implies underwounding.

Where am I wrong in my thinking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54059/why-is-compensatory-negative-supercoiling-generated-in-a-positively-supercoiling/